# Usage of function: goToPage() in TabbedHeaderPager

Tags: typescript, react-native

Im using TabbedHeaderPager in my project and i need to change tab programmatically and im trying to use function: goToPage() but i have problem to access the function.
I have tried as a prop and through pagerProps.

```
<TabbedHeaderPager
      goToPage={goToPage} // cant access function here
      pagerProps={{ 
        onScroll, //this function works
        goToPage // cant access function here
      }}    
      rememberTabScrollPosition
      onTopReached={() => console.log('onTopReached')}
      snapToEdge={false}
      parallaxHeight={400}
      backgroundColor={t.background.val}
      title={club.name ? club.name : 'My Golf Club'}
      foregroundImage={getClubLogoImage(club)}
      containerStyle={{
        
        minHeight: 800,
      }}
      backgroundImage={getClubBackgroundImage(club)}
      tabs={tabs}
    
    >
      
      {tabs.map((tab, index) => tab.content)}
    </TabbedHeaderPager>
```

Comment: Could you provide a link to the library that implements `TabbedHeaderPager `? I am not aware of this component.

Comment: here is the link to the libary: https://netguru.github.io/sticky-parallax-header/docs/headers/tabbed-header-pager
-version 1.0
-Tabbed Header Pager

Comment: sorry its my first time posting a question here

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The `goToPage` method is exposed by `TabbedHeaderPager` via `ref`, not via `pagerProps`. This has been introduced [in this issue here](https://github.com/netguru/sticky-parallax-header/issues/190).

> [...] in version 1.0.x, TabbedHeaderPager component (new TabbedHeader) have goToPage method exposed by ref. You can use it to programmatically jump between pages.

Hence, you can use it as follows.

```js
const pagerRef = React.useRef(null);

return <TabbedHeaderPager
      pagerProps={{ ref: pagerRef }}
    ...
</TabbedHeaderPager>
```

Then, call it as follows:

```js
pagerRef.current.goToPage(2);
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me! but it says ref.current.goToPage is undefined when i run this code

ref.current.goToPage(2);

Comment: @user19793518 Sorry, I have fixed my code. I have reached out to the developer of the library and he was so kind to show me how to use it. You must pass the `ref` to the `pagerProps`.